# How to understand the elementary modification?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

In the Friedman's book: *Algebraic Surfaces and Holomorphic Vector Bundle* , there is concept **elementary modification** at Ch2 Def15.

Let V is rank 2 bundle on X and L a line bundle on effective divisor D, W is elementary modification of V, if we have exact sequence:
    0$\to$W$\to$V$\to$j$_*$L$\to$0

> How to understand the elementary modification? If W is elementary
>   modification of V, how to get V$^\vee$ is obtained as an elementary
>   modification of W$^\vee$?

Comment: What do you mean by understand? For the second question: try dualizing the exact sequence you wrote down.

Comment: I mean some motivaction or some geometric meaning and I feel strange that I do not find this concept at other books about algebiaic surfaces.